# Replicated "is followed by" segment in bigquery, works for sessions but not users?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to replicate a basic segment I have in GA where I want to see all users who see one page then "is followed by" another page.

So I have tried 2 methods (subqueries AND self joins) which are both find when i look at sessions, my GA numbers perfectly match my bigquery numbers. Life is good.

However when i use the same method for users i'm off by a few, normally around 10-50 users out of 9000 or so. Anybody any ideas why?

Cheers.

My GA segment is very basic;
Page contains X
is followed by 
Page contains Y

My bigquery code looks like the following;

```
#standardsql
with
subq1 as 
(
SELECT distinct 
t.fullVisitorId as UserID,
hits.page.pagePath page, 
visitStartTime+hits.time as EventTime
FROM `ga-project` as t, 
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN  
    FORMAT_DATE("%y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)) AND
    FORMAT_DATE("%y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND 
    hits.page.pagepath like '%Y%'
),
subq2 as 
(
SELECT distinct 
t.fullVisitorId as UserID,
hits.page.pagePath page, 
visitStartTime+hits.time as EventTime
FROM `ga-project` as t, 
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN  
    FORMAT_DATE("%y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)) AND
    FORMAT_DATE("%y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND 
    hits.page.pagepath like '%X%'
)
select count(distinct a.userid) Page1toPage2 from subq1 a
join subq2 b on a.userid=b.userid and a.eventtime < b.eventtime
```

Comment: Did you try an unsampled report? I noticed that users are often sampled although the report says it's not.

Comment: I did, finding users by page and matching with BQ is fine... however my issue is getting my BQ user numbers to match my GA segments.

Comment: Check this out: https://adswerve.com/blog/why-google-analytics-users-dont-match-bigquery-users/

Answer (score 0):

The subqueries in BigQuery are like view rather than tables and that is why you may have different result at times. I recommend to [materialize the table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output#carefully_consider_materializing_large_result_sets). To avoid storage charges you can set a time to live to the table.